# How does AWS Cloudwatch alarms work when triggered together?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm, aws-auto-scaling

In my AWS elastic server setup, I have configured 4 Alarms

1. Add instance when CPU utilization > 20
2. Add instance when TargetResponceTime > 0.9
3. Remove instance when CPU utilization < 20
4. Remove instance when TargetResponceTime < 0.9

What will happen if two or more alarms triggered together?

For Example

- If alarm 1 and 2 triggered together will it add two instances?
- If alarm 1 and 4 triggered together will it remove an instance and add one or will it stay neutral?

The alarms are working fine, but I want to understand the mechanism behind alarm action execution.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your auto scaling group has a [cooldown period](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/Cooldown.html), so technically multiple actions cannot occur at the same time. The next action would occur after the cooldown period has passed.

This functionality is to stop exactly what you're talking about, with multiple instances scaling at once.

I think personally for what you're doing you should be making use of a [composite CloudWatch alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create_Composite_Alarm.html). By having an `OR` condition these 4 alarms could become 2, which would reduce the number of alarms you have to trigger an autoscaling action.

Comment: so you mean when the alarm 1 and 2 both are in the Alarm state, which everts the alarm triggered 1st will add the instance and wait the defined cooling period. Within that period if the Alarms went back to OK state, there will be no action based on the second alarm ?

Comment: So, this behavior is the same even if the triggered alarm is trying to add an instance or trying to remove a one?

Comment: Exactly whichever action triggers first will cause the action, the evaluation of alarms are not considered again until after the cooldown period.

Comment: awesome. Thank you very much for the explanation.